# Query variable can be no longer than 512 characters

Tags: php, suhosin

I'm struggling to read query variables that contain more than 512 characters in the `$_GET` array. If I parse the query string using `parse_string`, however, I can read it just fine from the resulting array.

Example:

```
# GET /test.php?foo=<string with 513 characters>&bar=bar HTTP/1.1

<?php
var_dump($_GET['foo']); # NULL
var_dump($_GET['bar']); # "bar"

parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $output);
var_dump($output['foo']); # <string with 513 characters>
?>
```

This makes no sense to me, since `$_GET` uses `parse_str` internally to derive the query variables from the query string. Am I missing something?

Comment: the obvious way around this would be to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: @Spudley: POST should only be used for non-idempotent requests.

Comment: I'm adding "Suhosin" to the tag list seeing as it seems to be the culprit

Comment: granted there may be good reasons for using GET rather than POST. I was suggesting it as a work-around, not a solution.

Comment: @Spudley: In that case, you are right. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PHP bug report. [#50449](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50449)

> GET parameters with a value longer than 512 characters don't show up in 
>   the $_GET and  $_REQUEST arrays. We've noticed this since upgrading to 
>   5.3.1

It says there  that it is Suhosin causing the behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure why Suhosin would impose this restriction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Johannes you're welcome. It's probably to prevent overflow attacks of some sort.