# String with more then 513 signs doesn't appear in $_GET

Tags: php, get, suhosin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query variable can be no longer than 512 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133536/query-variable-can-be-no-longer-than-512-characters)

I have switched form PHP 5.2 to "PHP 5.3.3-7 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan  5 2011 10:36:05)" and have very very strange problem.

When I have an URL for example: `domain.com/file.php?abc=<string>` and the length of this string is more then 513 signs, then the `$_GET` array is empty and doesn't have the element abc?

Why? Can anyopne help me? Is this a bug or can I handle it with some setting in the `php.ini`?

Is very importand, because my site doesn't work propertly now!

Comment: If you have a GET parameter that long then you have other problems...

Comment: There's a hard limit for URL length. I'm not sure if this is a web server issue or a PHP issue; in any case, you may want to pass the data as `POST` data instead, which is not limited.

Comment: Suhosin is the "problem" here. http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html  gives a default max length of 512. Can you change something about suhosin?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I don't see why having a GET parameter that long would be a problem. @zneak: POST is not *exactly* an alternative to GET, according to the HTTP specification.